# I need to handle the incoming mail using mailgun and this is not working

Tags: node.js, email, routes, webhooks, mailgun

I stuck somewhere when I need to receive email in mailgun i.e. Inbound API

I created  the routes and also using ngrok for handle localhost server.
Webhook API is not hitting

this is the route create in Mailgun

```
catch_all() Priority: 0
forward("https://2da8b7b8853f.ngrok.io/api/receive-mail")
store(notify="https://2da8b7b8853f.ngrok.io/api/receive-mail")
stop()
Some random description here
```

Controller

```
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer");
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: 'API_KEY', domain: 'mg.domain.io'});

exports.sendMail = (req, res) => {
    //working fine and receiving the mail.
}

exports.receiveMail = (req, res) => {
   mailgun.routes().list().then(response => console.log(response.items)).catch(error => 
   console.log(error));
   console.log('Mail received from webhook'); // not working
   res.status(200).json({
     response: req.body
   })
  }
```

routes.js

```
router.post('/api/send-mail', msgReplies.sendMail);
router.post('/api/receive-mail', msgReplies.receiveMail);
```

[image: Working fine when I call API from here]

Please help me what I am missing

I verified the routes by below line of code

```
mailgun.routes().list().then(response => console.log(response.items)).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @EhsanGondal, Yes I was using the wrong domain name. I just corrected the domain name and working fine.